# CakePHP2.6でAWSのS3をプラグインを使用して使いたいのですが

Tags: cakephp, aws

お世話になっております。

https://github.com/zaru/Cakephp2_AWS_S3_DataSource
このプラグインを使用してS3アップにしたいのですが、導入してページを開くと

Error: Class 'Aws\S3\S3Client' not found    
File: /var/www/html/cakephp/app/Plugin/AmazonWebServices/Model/Datasource/S3.php    
Line: 21

このようなエラーがでてしまいます。

S3のクライアントが認識されていないと思われるのですが、どこに何を記述していいのかわかりません。パケット名は記述したのですが、クライアントとはAWS、S3のどこの部分でしょうか？

use Aws\S3\Enum\CannedAcl;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
use Guzzle\Http\EntityBody;

class S3 extends DataSource {
        public $description = 'AmazonWebServices S3 File Controller';
        public $S3 = '';
        public $bucketName = '＊＊＊＊'; //パケット名入力

```
    public function __construct($config = array(), $autoConnect = true){
            parent::__construct($config);
            $this->S3 = S3Client::factory($config);
            $this->bucketName = $config['bucket_name'];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

このプラグインの動作にはAWS SDKのv2系がインストールされていることが前提のようです。

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/tree/2.8

から、v2系を取得して適切なパスを通すか、

```
composer require aws/aws-sdk-php:"2.*"
```

のようにComposerでバージョンを指定してインストールすると良いと思います。

(CakePHP 2系でComposerを利用する方法はGoogle等で検索してみてください。

なお、データソースとして利用することにこだわりが無ければ、AWS SDKのv3系を直接利用するのもありだと思います。

Comment: 補足として robmcvey/cakephp-amazon-s3 https://github.com/robmcvey/cakephp-amazon-s3  を紹介しておきます。こちらはSDKへの依存がないためプラグインのみで利用できます。